# Add only selected text to text value

Tags: jquery

I want add text of div to #inputString value (`value="text"`).
From -> `<div class="row">text</div>` or `<div class="row">anothertext</div>` etc. Same class different text.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.row').click(function() {
        var value = $(this).attr('.text');
        $('input#inputString').val(value);
    });
});​
```

Comment: What do you mean with *add only selected row's text*? How do you select a row in your HTML code?

Comment: I edited question, I hope its more clear now

Comment: And why do you use the `click` event? You want to add the text only if the user clicks on the textarea?

Comment: I'm sorry, i forget to rename click class to row. `    $('.row').click(function() {`

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle sample?

Comment: @Jonuux Then only replace `$(this).attr('.text');` by `$(this).text();`.

Comment: Yes !! this is it. was much simplier than i thougt :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the sparsity of detail, I can only suggest:

```
$('.row').click(function(){
    $(inputSelector).val($(this).text());
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RMukY/).

Where `inputSelector` is whatever selector you're using to select your `input` element.

Note that we use the `text()` method to retrieve the text of the element, *not* a text attribute. Although in some browsers the node may have a `text` property (but it's still not an attribute of the element).